# Select number of occurrences of a string in DataTable

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I need find out the number of times a persons name **string** appears in a DataTable.. Im trying to find out who has resolved the most tickets in 24 hours. I've been able to accomplish this using SQL below but I um un familiar with how to do to this using LINQ. The three columns from the SELECT statement are all varchar(MAX types)

SQL CODE

```
SELECT Assigned_Individual,Data_Output_Type,assigned_group, count(Assigned_Individual)
FROM [DATABASE].[DBO].[TABLENAME]
GROUP BY Assigned_Individual, Data_Output_Type, assigned_group
ORDER BY  count(1) desc
```

This will produce a result that will have an additional column telling me how many times the persons name "Assigned_Individual" has occurred in this table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit tricky in LINQ, but you can do it using the below code. I hope you like the sql style syntax:

```
var query = from table in tablename 
            group by new { table.Assigned_Individual, table.Data_Output_Type, table.assigned_group }
            into grp
            select new 
            {
                 grp.Key.AssignedIndividual,
                 grp.Key.Data_Output_Type,
                 grp.Key.assigned_group,
                 Count = grp.Count()
            };
```

Comment: Thanks Justin, This was exactly what I was looking for!